# Background color of div only certain height

Tags: html, css

I have a transparent div and i want to set background color to only 60% of the whole size of div.
Example: I have a content with image on my website. Let say that 60% of the content i want to have background color set to white, the upper part of the content stays transparent.

```
.test p{
    background-color: #f6d8d8;
}
.test p:first-child{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/
I want to have red only on last two paragraphs. The first paragraph should stay transparent, as its set in the outer div. How do i apply this styling?

I have changed refer : http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/1/

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML within your question, otherwise this question will be meaningless if JSFiddle goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gradient

```
.test{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6d8d8 0%,#f6d8d8 40%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%);
}
```

Comment: This is actually what am looking for. How do I set that 60% of my bottom div will have #f6d8d8?

Comment: Just be careful as if your paragraphs change size, the gradient will remain the same.

Comment: Not the same in absolute size, but still 60%

Comment: @Andriy Yes, good point. Still be careful if there are varying content heights though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the background, independent from your paragraphs, you could use a gradient:

```
.test{
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(246,216,216,1) 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(246,216,216,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 50%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 50%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6d8d8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/7/)

If it needs to be split exactly between the paragraphs, use one of the other `nth-...` solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, two posibilities:

[First example](http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/8/). You have a gradient and with % you can set up which % do you want to fill with that color.

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, #f6d8d8 70%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%);
```

And the other hand you can just change the location of your tag. With this example [Second example](http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/9/)

```
<div class="test">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give following way:

```
.test{
    background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, #f6d8d8 30%);
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/11/)

Comment: thank you this what i needed. I suggest please provide details as of what does 70% and 30% means so that other users can know exactly what changes they need. BTW thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

> **

```css
.test{
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%, rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(60%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(60%,rgba(246,216,216,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6d8d8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```css
.test{
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%, rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(60%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(60%,rgba(246,216,216,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 60%,rgba(246,216,216,1) 60%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6d8d8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultricies cursus placerat. Aenean euismod convallis scelerisque. Etiam eget ex dolor. Phasellus diam mi, egestas eu massa vel, pellentesque bibendum augue. Quisque porttitor neque mauris, ac vehicula magna porttitor eget. Phasellus nec interdum nunc. Quisque euismod nulla pellentesque enim posuere posuere. Nullam nunc nunc, efficitur nec interdum sit amet, malesuada pretium dui. Sed convallis felis ut laoreet ultricies.</p>

    <p>Phasellus vel convallis elit, at lacinia lectus. Vivamus sed libero at nibh dapibus auctor. Quisque aliquam facilisis turpis, quis tincidunt justo. Fusce sit amet porta ipsum. Vestibulum eget metus commodo, laoreet ex eget, pellentesque dolor. Cras ac vulputate nisl. Quisque tempus sapien condimentum, convallis metus egestas, vehicula erat. In vel purus risus. Maecenas tristique eget massa eget interdum. Pellentesque gravida ut mi vel maximus. Nulla nec justo mattis, ullamcorper sem at, tempor eros. Integer pretium vel nunc non ultrices. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi.</p>

    <p>Integer elementum nulla sit amet justo varius laoreet. Mauris nec porttitor est, tincidunt gravida dui. Duis tempor pharetra felis. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam convallis cursus turpis, eget finibus est suscipit eget. Aenean vitae eros nulla. Etiam congue ipsum velit, eu ultrices turpis tincidunt id. Morbi eu sodales lorem. Vivamus vel aliquet enim, sit amet tincidunt ex. Phasellus luctus nunc eget lobortis fermentum. Nullam ex felis, interdum ac odio sed, lacinia dignissim nisi. Aenean dolor lorem, placerat vitae suscipit et, aliquet vel leo. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind last two `<p> </p>` tags in one separate `<div> </div>` and apply `class="test"` to that div.

Here is Fiddle : [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/318wsehf/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try as follows:

```css
.test p:nth-child(2),p:nth-child(3){
        background-color: #f6d8d8;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <p>Phasellus vel convallis elit, at lacinia lectus. </p>

    <p>Integer elementum nulla sit amet justo varius laoreet. Mauris nec </p>
</div>
```

This is not my own answer. It is a improved version of one previous answer.

Answer (score -1):

please modify your CSS to

```
 .test{
   background: linear-gradient(to top, #f6d8d8 20%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%);
}
```

Comment: This will only colour the background of the paragraphs not the div.

Answer (score -1):

Put a second div containing the last two paragraphs. This would be best if you have other things going in the second parts.

```
<div>
<p>...</p>
<div class="test">
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/4/

Comment: before downvote or comment. First read the question properly Refer:-  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/318wsehf/ I want to have red only on last two paragraphs. The first paragraph should stay transparent, as its set in the outer div. How do i apply this styling?

Comment: Go back and read the whole question. The first section clearly stipulates the OP wants 60% of the div to have the red background colour, not just the paragraphs. They are just what happens to be in the div.

Comment: Jus see the second section it was mentioned for paragraph

Comment: Because that is what is inside the div.

Comment: Both does the same thing. I dont want to unnecessarily insert a tag it has a fix that can be done using css itself.

Comment: Not even nearly the same, putting a background color on the paragraph tags will leave the paragraph's margins matching the colour of the container div, in this case white streaks.

Comment: See that is what is required for him just refer the fiddle i have provided.

Comment: Sorry, but the only fiddle I can see provided by you is just the fiddle from the OP.